# yii2 Метод rules не выдает message

Tags: php, yii2

В чем проблема? вместе

> Недостаточно средств на счету!

он выводит

> Значение «Сумма» не должно превышать 70.

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['id', 'mon'], 'required'],
            ['id', 'exist', 'targetAttribute' => 'id',
                'targetClass'=> '\common\models\User',
                'message' => Yii::t('frontend', 'Такого реферала не существует.')
            ],
            ['mon', 'number', 'min' => 0, 'max' => Yii::$app->user->identity->mon,
                'message' => 'Недостаточно средств на счету!'
            ],
        ];
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

У валидатора типа `number` есть 2 вида пользовательских сообщений `tooBig` и `tooSmall` вместо стандартного `message`, замените `message` на `tooBig` и будет выводить ваше сообщение:

```
public function rules()
    {
        return [
            // username and password are both required
            [['id', 'mon'], 'required'],
            ['id', 'exist', 'targetAttribute' => 'id',
                'targetClass'=> '\common\models\User',
                'message' => Yii::t('frontend', 'Такого реферала не существует.')
            ],
            ['mon', 'number', 'min' => 0, 'max' => Yii::$app->user->identity->mon,
                'tooBig' => 'Недостаточно средств на счету!'
            ],
        ];
    }
```